# How to make a link with many elements in rails using haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, nested

I am very new in ruby, in rails and in haml. I was recoding a little site I have, and I was trying to create a link in wich is nested a few elements.

The structure I want to be outputted is this one:

```
<a href="somewhere">
    <span>
         <img src="/imgs/hello.png" />
    </span>
    <strong>6
        <em>Oct</em>
    </strong>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</a>
```

So I was trying it doing this (obviously its real indentation is one tab more than the parent element):

```
= link_to("somewhere") do 
    %span
        %img(src="/imgs/hello.png")
    %strong 6
        %em Oct
    %h1 Title
end
```

Wich for me seems to be logic. But it does not. It gives me this error:

*Inconsistent indentation: "  \t\t\t\t\t" was used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 1 tab.*

The error line number it's the first line after link_to; the %span element. So, I thought it was because I was not using link_to in a correct way, but seeing that the error talks about indentation problems and after trying it in many different ways, I cannot get it into run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
= link_to("somewhere") do
  %span
    %img(src="/imgs/hello.png")
    %strong 
      6
      %em Oct
  %h1 Title
```

Also, make sure in your editor you're using spaces as tabs. This will get rid of any funky business.

Comment: It hasn't worked first, but then I changed the editor to use spaces as you advice me, and it runs very well. It's a bit annoying for me to use spaces instead of tabs. :/ Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. You should probably accept the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit new on here as well and don't knew about the accept answer thing. Thanks again!